# Grunt compress : How could I only include runtime node module dependencies?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, package, mean-stack

My application is [MEAN stack](http://mean.io/) style. I would like to generate a package including all Nodejs and AngularJs files, so I could just unzip the package and run in other environments.

I use [grunt-contrib-compress](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compress) to compress and generate a zip file. Everything works well, but there are many development node modules are included, such as grunt*. All I need is the  runtime node modules which are defined in the package.json. It will dramatically reduce the package size.

I could include the node modules one by one, but is there a good way only include runtime modules while packaging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found a solution, which load the package.json and map the runtime dependencies into target folders.

```js
compress: {
      main: {
        options: {
          archive: 'myapp.zip'
        },
        files: [
          {src: ['dist/**','app/**','config/**','server.js'],dest:'.'},
          {src: Object.keys(require('./package.json').dependencies).map(function(module){
            return "node_modules/" +module+"/**"
          }),dest:'.'},
        ]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same question today, and after asking and coming up with a very similar solution, I have found your question. Here is my, similar but slightly different approach:

```
function getDependencies(pkg) {
    return Object.keys(pkg.dependencies).map(function(val) { return val + '/**'; });
}

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var pkg = grunt.file.readJSON('package.json');
    var config = {
        pkg: pkg,
        clean: ["public/"],
        compress: {
            validate: {
                options: {
                    archive: 'public/Lambda.zip'
                },
                files: [
                    { expand: true, cwd: 'src/', src: ['**'], dest: '/' },
                    { expand: true, cwd: 'node_modules/', src: getDependencies(pkg), dest: '/node_modules' }
                ]
            }
        }
    };

    grunt.initConfig(config);

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compress');

    grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean', 'compress']);
}
```